# Display Months in dropdown for filtering in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I want to create a view over a content type. Over this page I want a select list of Months to filter the content by month.

Is there any module or how can I achieve this by view?

Answer (score 0):

The date module can do this however there is one small caveat. I do not believe this will work if you are using fields such as node created date or node updated date. This approach will only work for date fields that are added to the content type.

If you need to filter by node created or node updated date then you can either build a custom filter for views (which is not for the faint of heart) or you can possibly try this module http://drupal.org/project/views_daterange. I have never used the module but it sounds like it might do what you need (but is only released for Drupal 6).